# D3.js.nest rollup with cumulative sum using reduce

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying get cumulative sum from existing array using `D3.nest`.

The learnjsdata.com site has this [example](http://learnjsdata.com/iterate_data.html) using `reduce`:

```
var landSum = data.reduce(function(sum, d) {
  return sum + d.land_area;
}, 0);
console.log(landSum);
```

I tried to adapt this to `d3.nest` `rollup` as shown below.

```js
var caseByDate = 
    [
      {
        "report_date": "2020-03-30",
        "case_count": 1
      },
      {
        "report_date": "2020-04-03",
        "case_count": 1
      },
      {
        "report_date": "2020-04-07",
        "case_count": 1
      }
    ]
    
var caseByDateCum = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.report_date; })
    .rollup(function(v) { 
        return v.reduce(function(sum, d) {
            return sum + d.case_count;
          }, 0);
     })
    .entries(caseByDate)
    .map(function(group) {
        return {
            report_date: group.key,
            cum_case_count: group.value
        }
    });

console.log(caseByDateCum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

But does not return cumulative sum, it just returns original data in cum_case_count. I am expecting the result to be:

```
var caseByDateCum = 
[
  {
    "report_date": "2020-03-30",
    "cum_case_count": 1
  },
  {
    "report_date": "2020-04-03",
    "cum_case_count": 2
  },
  {
    "report_date": "2020-04-07",
    "cum_case_count": 3
  }
]
```

I can't find anything searching that helps to described how to use `reduce` in `d3.nest` `rollup` to get cumulative totals.

`Reduce` `sum` is supposed to be an 'accumulator', and the `v` value is an array of numbers grouped by the `key` value. So it should work inside `rollup`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to use pure javascript:

```js
let caseByDate = [
    {
        "report_date": "2020-03-30",
        "case_count": 1
    },
    {
        "report_date": "2020-04-03",
        "case_count": 1
    },
    {
        "report_date": "2020-04-07",
        "case_count": 1
    }
];


caseByDate.forEach(function (e) {
    this.count = (this.count || 0) + e.case_count;
    e.case_count = this.count;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(caseByDate);
```

Comment: Thx but looking for answer specifically for `d3.nest rollup`